# Next.js - Docker env vars are not being picked up

Tags: docker, next.js

I'm using Next.js and trying to dockerize my app - however the environment variables are being picked up from my docker-compose file as expected. I keep seeing `undefined` despite having them prepended with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

I found that if I copy the .env file it works as expected.

Any ideas what's going on here and how I can actually define them in my docker-compose file - which (simplified) currently looks like:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  front:
    image: mywork
    environment:
        NEXT_PUBLIC_API: 'http://localhost:8080'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Is it acceptable to just have the .env file in the docker image? I've been reading its not a good idea. So whats the next.js workaround here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the environment format should be

```
front:
  environment:
    - NEXT_PUBLIC_API=http://localhost:8080
```